# How to receive Event Key value from Bitbucket to Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline using Bitbucket Server Integration plugin

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket, webhooks, bitbucket-pipelines, multibranch-pipeline

I installed the plugin [`Bitbucket Server Integration`](https://plugins.jenkins.io/atlassian-bitbucket-server-integration/) in jenkins & able to receive webhook to trigger build jobs with [this setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbodE.png).
From the logs also I can see different event key is received.

> Processed 4 branches (query complete)
> [Mon Jan 16 13:23:53 IST 2023] com.atlassian.bitbucket.jenkins.internal.trigger.BitbucketWebhookConsumer$`BitbucketSCMHeadPullRequestEvent UPDATED event` from code-repository with timestamp Mon Jan 16 13:23:52 IST 2023 processed in 0.55 sec
> [Mon Jan 16 16:23:04 IST 2023] Received com.atlassian.bitbucket.jenkins.internal.trigger.BitbucketWebhookConsumer$`BitbucketSCMHeadEvent UPDATED event` from code-repository with timestamp Mon Jan 16 16:23:04 IST 2023
> git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /var/lib/jenkins/caches/git-deb6ea23f7071e9d585c1b40bdf92144/.git

Now I want to perform different actions based on the received `eventKey`. Like doing extra validation if received event is for a Pull Request.

I understand we can read the JSON payload for the webhook trigger (from `${JENKINS_URL}/bitbucket-server-webhook/trigger`). There is also a way to read it from `Request Header: X-Event-Key`.

[Bitbucket Webhook request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OarZd.png)

But I cannot find a way to read/print it in Jenkins console.
Can anyone help with it please?